# Using Long/Lat coords to find corresponding Census Tracts

Tags: r, geolocation, coordinates

I am trying to use long/lat coords to find what census tract they fall in. This is what my data currently looks like.

```
Latitude    Longitude
38.040357   -84.490224
39.8366017  -86.2430572
38.1952533  -84.3974234
38.1485095  -84.5342804
38.1485095  -84.5342804
...
```

What sort of package, actual code, or anything else I would need to use to get the result I am looking for? I have the tigris package but I don't know how to use it

Comment: Hi HannBeez, welcome to SO. Unfortunately, your question is considered off-topic for this site. SO is for debugging code and programming issues and not for advice regarding packages etc. As such, your question is likely to be closed. Having said that, if you search for questions regarding the `sf` package, "census", "points", and `st_intersects()`, you will find a number of answers. Good luck!

Comment: What is a "Census Tract"? Where are they defined? _How_ are they defined? It's good that you provided sample lat and lon data, but for us to know how to help find the corresponding tracts, we need to know how they are defined. I agree with @LTyrone in that the `sf` package is likely to be used in a solution. (I'll assume that a census tract is an area defined in shapefiles or similar, where we cannot assume rectangularity or such.)

Comment: Thank you!! I will absolutely check out some other places for advice regarding the sf package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Census Tract from Lat/Lon using tigris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248394/get-census-tract-from-lat-lon-using-tigris)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick intro to `sf` and some coordinates. For the sake of fun, I'll use some Cartographic Boundary files from the US Census Bureau, found at https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html. I downloaded "States", specifically `cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip` and extracted to a temporary directory.

```r
### shapefile
US <- sf::read_sf("~/tmp/cb/cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp")
### your data
dat <- structure(list(Latitude = c(38.040357, 39.8366017, 38.1952533, 38.1485095, 38.1485095), Longitude = c(-84.490224, -86.2430572, -84.3974234, -84.5342804, -84.5342804)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

We need to convert your data to an `sf`-object and apply the appropriate CRS. The data in that shapefile is define on NAD83.

```r
sf::st_crs(US)
# Coordinate Reference System:
#   User input: NAD83 
#   wkt:
# GEOGCRS["NAD83",
#     DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
#         ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
#             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
#     PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
#         ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
#     CS[ellipsoidal,2],
#         AXIS["latitude",north,
#             ORDER[1],
#             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
#         AXIS["longitude",east,
#             ORDER[2],
#             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
#     ID["EPSG",4269]]
```

If you don't know what "CRS" means, you might have a lot of problems here, since ... changing the datum of coordinates can be minor or could mean crossing boundaries. If the coordinates were derived via a somewhat modern gathering device then it might be safe to assume that your coordinates are WGS84 (EPSG:4326). I will ***BLINDLY*** assuming this for the sake of this answer, but please do your due diligence and verify. Census results may be silently wrong if you do not.

```r
sf::st_set_crs(US, 4326)
datsf <- sf::st_as_sf(dat, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude"), crs = 4326L)
```

We can plot both just for fun. I'll use `ggplot2`, but it's not the only way. (Somewhat comically, the islands on the far right of the screen are actually the western-most points of Alaska's island chain. The "Rat Islands" such as Semisopochnoi and Amchitka, are "positive" longitude, whereas the rest of the island chain and all of mainland Alaska and CONUS are all "negative" longitude.)

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(US) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = datsf, color = "red")
```

[image]

Let's check where your points land. (Note that if you did not do your homework and make sure that the CRS of `US` and your data are the same, then this is going to fail. Please don't blindly assume, units and datums are there for a reason, and they are not intended to be compatible.)

```r
ind <- sf::st_intersects(datsf, US)
ind
# Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 5, where the predicate was `intersects'
#  1: 48
#  2: 54
#  3: 48
#  4: 48
#  5: 48
```

And we can better visualize this with

```r
ggplot(US[unique(unlist(ind)),]) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = datsf, color = "red")
```

[image]

So the regions in which your points lie? Rows 1 and 3-5 are in "48" (Kentucky) and row 2 is in "54" (Indiana),

```r
US[unique(unlist(ind)),]
# # A tibble: 2 × 10
#   STATEFP STATENS  AFFGEOID    GEOID STUSPS NAME     LSAD         ALAND     AWATER                                                                    geometry
#   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>       <chr> <chr>  <chr>    <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>                                                          <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>
# 1 21      01779786 0400000US21 21    KY     Kentucky 00    102279490672 2375337755 (((-89.40565 36.52817, -89.39869 36.54233, -89.39681 36.55197, -89.39663 3…
# 2 18      00448508 0400000US18 18    IN     Indiana  00     92789302676 1538002829 (((-88.09776 37.90403, -88.09448 37.90596, -88.08624 37.90571, -88.07145 3…
```

which you can perhaps formalize with

```r
dat$State <- US$NAME[unlist(ind)]
dat
#   Latitude Longitude    State
# 1 38.04036 -84.49022 Kentucky
# 2 39.83660 -86.24306  Indiana
# 3 38.19525 -84.39742 Kentucky
# 4 38.14851 -84.53428 Kentucky
# 5 38.14851 -84.53428 Kentucky
```

Comment: This was more helpful than you could possibly know. Thank you so much for the clear explanations. I will be testing out your suggestions!